# Recursive segue in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

[image]

I have two `UIViewControllers`, from `GreenViewController` button I created a `model segue` to `WhiteViewController.

and

from `WhiteViewController` button I created `model segue` back to `GreenViewController`.

App is running without error, but this is something I am not used to when programmatically presenting a `model view controller`, we always dismiss the `presented view controller`. But these `green and white view controllers` keep presenting each other no dismiss, its like parent display child and child displaying parent.

Why `UIStoryBoard` allowing this wrong approach and why App is running with out error or is there any thing that I am missing?

Comment: In your case error is logical. Modern compilers cannot catch such errors. You probably will run out of memory putting this controllers to stack.

Comment: Why would Apple spend time trying to prevent people from creating an infinite loop? It's not their concern to try and prevent people from bad programming.